# Upgraded to Rails 3.1, changed to jQuery, now my ajax does not seem to update field

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a website (GiggleTrigger.com) where users can vote for punchlines that they think are funny (by clicking the "giggle" button).  This was set up to happen through an ajax call, but now after upgrading to Rails 3.1 I seem to have broken this.  I tried to update the javascript to jQuery, but it is still not working.

**Here is the old javascript code (placed in views/votes/create.js.rjs):**

```
page.replace_html "vote_total_#{@punchline.id}", "#{@punchline.votes.size}"
```

**Here is the attempted updated code (placed in views/votes/create.js.erb):**

```
$("#vote_total_#{@punchline.id}").html("<%= escape_javascript render @punchline.votes.size  %>");
```

**Here is the html (placed in views/punchlines/_punchline.html.erb):**

```
<span id="vote_total_<%= punchline.id %>" class="punchline_votes">
    <%= punchline.votes.size %>
</span>
<span id="vote_button">
    <%= button_to 'giggle', punchline_votes_path(:punchline_id => punchline), :remote => true %>
</span>
```

**Here is the controller code (placed in controllers/votesController.rb):**

```
class VotesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @punchline  = Punchline.find(params[:punchline_id])
    @vote       = @punchline.votes.build params[:vote]
    @vote.user  = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @vote.save
        format.js        
        format.html { redirect_to @punchline }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to root }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

* I am getting this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `model_name' for Fixnum:Class):
  1: $("#vote_total_#{@punchline.id}").html("<%= escape_javascript render @punchline.votes.size  %>");
      app/views/votes/create.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_votes_create_js_erb__1782616409977082835_2168430380'
      app/controllers/votes_controller.rb:7:in `create
```

**Because this seems like an issue with an integer being passed, I add the .to_s method,like this:**

```
$("#vote_total_#{@punchline.id}").html("<%= escape_javascript render @punchline.votes.size.to_s  %>");
```

**But I get this error:**

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial votes/1, application/1 with {:handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee], :formats=>[:js, :html], :locale=>[:en, :en]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/Daniel/Sites/giggle/app/views"
  * "/Users/Daniel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@giggle/gems/devise-1.5.3/app/views"
):
    1: $("#vote_total_#{@punchline.id}").html("<%= escape_javascript render @punchline.votes.size.to_s  %>");
  app/views/votes/create.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_votes_create_js_erb__1782616409977082835_2187483480'
  app/controllers/votes_controller.rb:7:in `create'
```

**I try to add a partial like so:**

```
$("#vote_total_#{@punchline.id}").html("<%= escape_javascript render :partial => 'punchline', :object => @punchline.votes.size  %>");
```

**But then I get this error:**

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial votes/punchline, application/punchline with {:handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee], :formats=>[:js, :html], :locale=>[:en, :en]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/Daniel/Sites/giggle/app/views"
  * "/Users/Daniel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@giggle/gems/devise-1.5.3/app/views"
):
    1: $("#vote_total_#{@punchline.id}").html("<%= escape_javascript render :partial => 'punchline', :object => @punchline.votes.size.to_s  %>");
  app/views/votes/create.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_votes_create_js_erb__1782616409977082835_2185760740'
  app/controllers/votes_controller.rb:7:in `create'
```

When I click the giggle button, a vote gets added to the model object, but it does not update the view unless I refresh the page.  Obviously, I want that to happen through ajax without a refresh.  Thank You!

Comment: VALUES (?,?,?,?) is ok. The ? are then interpolated with the values in the array (see the rest of the log line)

Comment: Try "puts params.inspect" and see if you're getting values in the post request...

Comment: Define "not working"--looks like the ID is sent and the action is firing.

Comment: Dave, by "not working" I mean that the total does not change after I click the vote button until I reload the page.  The goal is to get it to change automatically (like I had it before upgrading).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out.  The old prototype code:

```
page.replace_html "vote_total_#{@punchline.id}", "#{@punchline.votes.size}"
```

uses #{} to post the ruby data into the element.  But jQuery uses the # to represent an id.  So, I changed my jquery selector from #{}  to  <%= %> and it solved the problem:

```
$("#vote_total_<%= @punchline.id %>").html("<%=@punchline.votes.size%>");
```

Answer (score 1):

you could add

```
if(!document.getElementById("vote_total_#{@punchline.id}")) {
  alert("Id doesn't exist: " + "vote_total_#{@punchline.id}");
}
```

To your javascript and that will alert you if the id is bad. Bad meaning that an element with that id doesn't exist. I'm curious what actually get's generated for the client, this is ajax, all client side stuff for the most part.

You should also check the console (firebug or the webkit inspector) and turn on XMLHttpRequest logging, and see if any real ajax is being done when you click Giggle :D

-For the webkit inspector, there is a gear icon in the very bottom right corner of the window. click this and you'll see the option to log XHR's.

-If someone could comment for Firebug, that'd be awesome.

Comment: The id is good.  XMLHttpRequest logging is on, but not giving me any errors.

Comment: Are any XHR's even occurring?

Comment: I don't know how to answer that.  I think there are.

Comment: I'm getting the right response in the console: 
$('#vote_total_#{@punchline.id}').html('1');

But it is still not rendering.

Comment: You can see XHR logging action by turning it on and just going to facebook or pretty much any big website.